# Верстка каркаса html шаблона

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Такая проблема, есть макет https://jsfiddle.net/61htzzrx/

```css
header {
  background-color: #FBD293;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  height: 50px;
}
.middle {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: calc(100% - 50px);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.middle > .left-sidebar {
  background-color: #CBE6A3;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  padding-bottom: 160px;
  width: 100px;
}
.left-sidebar > .blocks {
  background: #e6a3a3;
  height: 400px;
}
.middle > .content {
  background: #A3CCFF;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  width: 500px;
}
.left-sidebar footer {
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: #D6A3E6;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="middle">

<aside class="left-sidebar">
  <div class="blocks">
    Блоки, должны быть всегда на виду
  </div>

  <footer>
    Футер<br>всегда внизу
  </footer>
</aside>


<main class="content">
  Контент, должен быть прижат к низу
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</main>
</div>
```

Надо прижать `.content` к низу и сделать так, чтобы меню всегда оставалось на виду (перемещалось вместе с прокруткой)

Сейчас у меня такие проблемы:

1) Черная полоска справа от `aside` идет не до конца страницы, и фон `aside` тоже

2) `.blocks` должен прокручиваться вместе со страницей и не залезать на `footer`

Comment: каркас не правильно сделан, можно изменить? или только со стилями работать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Сайдбар клеится внутрь блока при помощи `position: sticky`, для кроссбраузерности не забудьте использовать полифилл.
2. Остальное — флексбокс.

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

header {
  background-color: #FBD293;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  height: 50px;
  width: 600px;
}

.middle {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.left-sidebar {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #CBE6A3;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100px;
}

.left-sidebar__blocks-holder {
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.blocks {
  background: #e6a3a3;
  height: 400px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.content {
  background: #A3CCFF;
  min-height: 800px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.left-sidebar footer {
  height: 100px;
  background: #D6A3E6;
}
```

```html
<header></header>

<div class="middle">
  <aside class="left-sidebar">
    <div class="left-sidebar__blocks-holder">
      <div class="blocks">
        Блоки, должны быть всегда на виду
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
      Футер<br>всегда внизу
    </footer>
  </aside>

  <main class="content">
    Контент, должен быть прижат к низу
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Смотри на footer и sidebar не один не на месте

Comment: Хорошая ли практика применять ко всему box-sizing: border-box; ?

Comment: @Fangog если понимаешь, что делаешь, то да :-)

Answer (score 3):

Вот пример по тем критериям которые вы сказали что хотите поправить:

Это стандартная верстка `CSS` не знаю что объяснить, если будут вопросы скажите.

Вот код:

```css
 body{
   margin: 0;
 }
 header {
  background-color: #FBD293;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  height: 50px;
 }

 .middle {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: calc(100% - 50px);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #fff;
 }

 .middle > .left-sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-co
  background-color: #CBE6A3;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
 }

 .left-sidebar > .blocks {
  background: #e6a3a3;
  height: 100%;
 }

 .middle > .content {
  position: relative;
  background: #A3CCFF;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  width: 500px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
 }
 .content_footer{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   background: yellow;
 }
 body>footer {
  height: 100px;
  background: #D6A3E6;
 }
```

```html
 <header></header>
 <div class="middle">
   <aside class="left-sidebar">
  <div class="blocks">
    Блоки, должны быть всегда на виду
  </div>
   </aside>
   <main class="content">
  <div class="content_footer">
    Контент, должен быть прижат к низу
  </div>
   </main>
 </div>
 <footer>
   Футер<br>всегда внизу
 </footer>
```